# "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload" when I have uploaded 100 videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When uploading videos to my channel using YouTube Data Api, I get an error message "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload" when I have uploaded 100 videos.

I have checked the quota and it has not reached the limit.

Is there any way to resolve this error or upload more than 100 videos?

Comment: The error occurs when 100 videos are uploaded in one day.

After a day has passed, I can upload up to 100 videos again.

Comment: Have you read [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)?

Comment: Yes.
However, there is an explanation for "quota" but not for this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to the YouTube Data api its [quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) costs.

If it had been you would have seen this error message

> quotaExceeded (403)    quotaExceeded   The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.

This error is realted to a limitation with in YouTube itself. A user can max upload X videos to YouTube per day depending upon their region / location.

## Support [Common uploading errors](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10383400?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdaily-upload-limit-reached-you-can-upload-more-videos-in-hours)

[image]